# Quickly generate multiple hillshades from DEMs in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, dem, hillshade, data-frame

In ArcGIS Desktop I would usually use ImageAnalyst app where it was easy to quickly generate hillshade from DEMs that are in data frame. But I can't find anything similar in ArcGIS Pro version, except generating hillshades through Hillshade Tool (lasts longer).

Answer (score 0):

Click the on the imagery tab on top ribbon. Raster Functions > Surface. This quickly generates hillshades, aspects, slope, and any other surface calculation you might need. Just don't forget to save the layers you need.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the symbology settings for a raster has a "Shaded Relief" option and Pro just does this on the fly now. This is performant enough for most purposes, including while I'm projecting on the fly. That said, I am working on something with an extremely large dataset that I wanted to pre-compute as a hillshade, rather than doing it on the fly.

Tom's solution worked well for me. That creates a new layer with the same source as my DEM. But unlike just symbolizing as a hillshade, when I do an identify, the values of this new layer are the stretched 0-255 grayscale values from the hillshade. If I go to the context menu for that layer > data > export raster, then it saves a new raster layer with just the hillshade.